# how to add multiple results of 1 query together as one value mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to get multiple results figured together of a query.

Some information beforehand:
I am making a system where managers can assign a employee to a company with information like how many hours they will work there that week etc.

Now there needs to be a limit for a employee when i assign the employee 2 times in 1 week number that they can't work more then 40 hours in that week number.

i have a form before this script and i select uitzendkrachtid 1 and weeknummer 1 in this form.

My script is:

```
        $uitzendkracht = $_POST['uitzend'];
        $bedrijf = $_POST['bedrijf'];
        $uren = $_POST['uren'];
        $dagen = $_POST['dagen'];
        $weeknummer = $_POST['week'];
        $bijzonderheden = $_POST['bijzonderheden'];

        $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                               FROM werk
                               WHERE uitzendkrachtid = '".$uitzendkracht."'
                               AND weeknummer = '".$weeknummer."'");


        while($row = mysql_Fetch_array($query2))
              {

               $row['uren'];


              }

My database:

    werkid   uitzendkrachtid  bedrijfid  accountid  uren  dagen   weeknummer   bijzonderheden
    1        1                1          1          25    3       1            geen
    2        1                1          1          40    5       1            geen

This contains the needed id's and weeknumbers and hours of the employee.
uren = hours
dagen = days 
weeknummer = weeknumber
```

Now my problem is:

When i `echo $row['uren'];` i get the result 4025 stuck to each other the 2 results are 40 and 25.

What i want is that these results get figured together to 65 is there a way to do this ?
I tryed everything explode and then [0] + [ 1 ] with the results etc but nothing worked.
I also checked this site for a solution but cannot find anything related to this problem.
Anyone knows a good solution for this?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(uren) as total
                           FROM werk
                           WHERE uitzendkrachtid = '".$uitzendkracht."'
                           AND weeknummer = '".$weeknummer."'");

   $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query2);
   echo $row['total'];
```

Answer (score 0):

change your query to Something like

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(uren) as result 
                           FROM werk
                           WHERE uitzendkrachtid = '".$uitzendkracht."'
                           AND weeknummer = '".$weeknummer."'");
```

And you will get addition in $row['result']

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` in your query,

```
$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(`uren`) 
                               FROM werk
                               WHERE uitzendkrachtid = '".$uitzendkracht."'
                               AND weeknummer = '".$weeknummer."'");
```

**Output**

```
65
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but answers above are better for my problem